# Сборка консольного приложения под Linux в NET7

Tags: c#, linux, .net, .net-core, .net-7

Мне нужно собрать консольное приложение C# для Linux, но в свойствах проекта, в графе `Целевая ОС` есть разные платформы, включая Mac, iOS и т.д., но только не Linux с его дистрибутивами. Гуглил, пробовал менять `.csproj` вручную, сейчас он выглядит так:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Hello_World</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Если убрать `OutputType Exe`, то собирает DLL.
Команда `dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -f net7.0` так же не дает нужного результата. В лучшем случае собирает без расширения исполняемого файла, что тоже не запустить на линуксе. SDK NET7 установлены, никаких пакетов, связанных с Linux в инсталлере не обнаружил, сам проект без внешних зависимостей - простейший Hello World из трех строк.

Comment: *"В лучшем случае собирает без расширения исполняемого файла, что тоже не запустить на линуксе."* - а что мешает?

Comment: Дилетантский вопрос, но я не понимаю, как открывать файл без расширения. И я думаю, что оно должно быть так или иначе

Comment: Его надо не открывать, а запускать. В линуксе у исполнимых файлов обычно нет расширения (если это не скрипты)

Comment: Его точно нельзя выполнить, думаю, что он собран аналогично .exe

Comment: Его совершенно точно можно выполнить. Что вы понимаете под *"собран аналогично .exe"* и почему это плохо?

Comment: Я понял, что неверно понимал суть проблемы. Вы правы, спасибо

Comment: нативно исполняемому файлу просто дайте права на выполнение `chmod +x ./имя_файла`. Для dll дотнетовских, нужно выполнить `dotnet run` https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run